# Flutter replace static data with api

Tags: flutter

I have an app which showing static data and models.

This is the structure

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String normalPrice;
  final String discountPrice;
  final double ratingValue;
  final String description;
  final bool isOffer;
  final List<String> images;
  final List<String> sizes;
  final List<String> colors;

  const Product({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.normalPrice,
    this.discountPrice,
    this.ratingValue,
    this.description,
    this.images,
    this.sizes,
    this.colors,

    this.isOffer,
  });
}


List<Product> productList = [
  Product(
      id: 1,
      title: "Nike Air Zoom Tempo Next",
      image: "assets/images/products/1_0.jpg",
      discountPrice: "0",
      normalPrice: "150",
      ratingValue: 4.0,
      isOffer: false,
      colors: [
        '0xFFF6625E',
        '0xFF836DB8',
        '0xFFDECB9C',
      ],
      description:
          "The Nike Air Zoom Tempo Next% mixes durability with a design that helps push you towards your personal best. The result is a shoe built like a racer, but made for your everyday training routine.",
      images: [
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_1.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_4.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_2.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_3.png",
      ],
      sizes: [
        "9",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
      ]
  ),
  Product(
      id: 2,
      title: "Nike Air Jordan Star",
      image: "assets/images/products/2_0.jpg",
      discountPrice: "50",
      normalPrice: "100",
      ratingValue: 4.0,
      isOffer: true,
      description:
          "With details inspired by the first release, the Air Jordan 3 Retro SE uses genuine leather and premium textiles to recreate the classic. It features Air cushioning in the heel and forefoot, plus denim-like overlays embellished with the iconic elephant print.",
      images: [
        "assets/images/products/2_0.jpg",
        "assets/images/products/2_1.jpg",
        "assets/images/products/2_2.jpg",
        "assets/images/products/2_3.jpg",
      ]),
];
```

Now i want to show the data from api. I need to know is it possible i can call api in same file and as the static productList are working in whole app ill call data from api and call it in productList so in all app my api products will show ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to make API calls.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

static Future<List<Product>> getProductsList()async{
  // Makes a get request to api
  // http package provides other requests too
  // checkout docs https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/http-library.html
  final response = await http.get('endpoint');

  if(response.statusCode!=200){
    print('Response is not 200');
    return [];
  }

  // assuming your API response is in json
  final decodedProductList = jsonDecode(resonse.body);

  // assuming your API response is a List of product
  // [
  //    {
  //      ...product
  //    }
  // ]
  return decodedProductList.map<Product>((map)=>Product.fromMap(map)).toList();
}
```

and your `product.dart` file should be

```dart
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String normalPrice;
  final String discountPrice;
  final double ratingValue;
  final String description;
  final bool isOffer;
  final List<String> images;
  final List<String> sizes;
  final List<String> colors;

  const Product({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.normalPrice,
    this.discountPrice,
    this.ratingValue,
    this.description,
    this.isOffer,
    this.images,
    this.sizes,
    this.colors,
  });
  
  /// Creates a [Map] with class fields.
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'image': image,
      'title': title,
      'normalPrice': normalPrice,
      'discountPrice': discountPrice,
      'ratingValue': ratingValue,
      'description': description,
      'isOffer': isOffer,
      'images': images,
      'sizes': sizes,
      'colors': colors,
    };
  }
  
  /// Creates a instance of [Product] from [Map].
  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
  
    return Product(
      id: map['id'],
      image: map['image'],
      title: map['title'],
      normalPrice: map['normalPrice'],
      discountPrice: map['discountPrice'],
      ratingValue: map['ratingValue'],
      description: map['description'],
      isOffer: map['isOffer'],
      images: List<String>.from(map['images']),
      sizes: List<String>.from(map['sizes']),
      colors: List<String>.from(map['colors']),
    );
  }
}
```